# Is it possible to highlight element on a web page and avoid triggering page events?

Tags: javascript, highlight

Is it possible to highlight element on a web page and avoid triggering page events?  I want to highlight elements on a page while automating it but I do not want to trigger any change events in the BODY.

I was looking at `jGrowl` because it doesn't change anything in the BODY tag of the HTML page (just the HEAD tag) to show something on the page.    But, rather than that, I want to position a transparent highlight over an element in the page by absolute positioning it.

Comment: Wouldn't said absolute element not be in the dom too?

Comment: Are you really sure that jGrowl doesn't add or change anything in the DOM? (rhetorical question)

Comment: @Juhana  - I think what I mean is that if there is a onClick event on the HTML BODY tag, then injecting JS into the HEAD tag shouldn't/wouldn't trigger the event.

Comment: Right, but if the injected script results in something being shown on the page, it must have done it by manipulating the DOM.

Comment: Ok, I clarified my question a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to highlight element on a web page without modifying the DOM?

No.

If you want to make a new element to overlay on top of an existing one, the new one has to be added to the page (DOM change).

If you want to change the style of an existing DOM node you would need to either change a stylesheet (DOM change), change a style rule (DOM change), or change an inline style attribute (DOM change).

Comment: So, if I am trying to avoid triggering change events in the BODY of a page, it seems that making a change in the HEAD tag would be ok, right?

Comment: @djangofan, you had said "without modifying the DOM". That includes the `<head>`. Now, you can change styles in the `<head>` but that's also likely to affect nodes in the `<body>`. Style changes could trigger animations which trigger events. You could attempt to use invalid markup by adding a `<div>` somewhere it doesn't belong, but that's likely to run into cross-browser issues.

Comment: Thanks.  I edited my question.  If you want to you can change your answer to better match my question. Sorry.   You just made me realize my question could have been worded more carefully.